# Can't find source of PHP SQL loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

Simple question for you guys - I'm trying to submit data to a table in a database and it does so successfully, before continuing to add an infinite number of blank rows to the table.

Here's the code:

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$about = $_POST['about'];
$msg  = $_POST['message'];

$con = mysql_connect("DATABASE","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$database = mysql_select_db("benpearl_co_uk_db", $con);
if(!$database) {
    die('Houston, we have a problem: ' . mysql_error());
}

    $sql="INSERT INTO contact (name, email, about, message) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$about', '$msg')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
        {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }

?>
    <script language="JavaScript">
    self.location="?email=1";
    </script>
```

Just to reiterate, I have no problem in connecting to the database or successfully putting the values from the form into the table. However once the values are inputted the page continually refreshes, adding blank lines to the table.

What's going wrong with my code here?

Comment: tick that green thingy near the answer which you find most accurate.

Comment: Just in case: You know that your code is vulnerable to SQL injections?

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise! I'll go through ticking my answers from now on. Thanks for the heads up ;)

Comment: And I'll work on a way to stop SQL injections. I'm just working baby steps at the moment! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always redirect to the the same page with:

```
self.location="?email=1";
```

Try something like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO contact (name, email, about, message) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$about', '$msg')";

if (mysql_query($sql, $con))
{
    header('Location: $other_page');
}

die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thank you for your help - originally this file was included on a different PHP page and I forgot that I had isolated this as a separate page to post the form details. How stupid. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @ben-pearl-kahan Hi Ben, there is no need to answer same comment to every one. Just try the solution and upvote if you find is useful and check the correct, and finally: enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
self.location="?email=1";
</script>
```

Self.location redirects the browser, you are redirecting to the same page with the addition of the url parameter `email = 1` which of course runs the script again causing an infinite loop. You should check whether `$_POST` contains valid values and only then insert into the database.

Comment: Thank you for your help - originally this file was included on a different PHP page and I forgot that I had isolated this as a separate page to post the form details. How stupid. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's exactly what your code does:

- on the server side write a DB row
- return page to client, that contains `<script language="JavaScript">self.location="?email=1";</script>`
- which in turn makes the page refresh.

You would need to make the JS part conditional.

Comment: Thank you for your help - originally this file was included on a different PHP page and I forgot that I had isolated this as a separate page to post the form details. How stupid. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you should run the insert only when the button submit is clicked if you have , so even when you load the page again it will not insert again the data

try doing this

```
   if (isset($_POST['submit']))     //then run your insert sql
   {

    $sql="INSERT INTO contact (name, email, about, message) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$about', '$msg')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
     {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
     }
     }
```